# Python text processing: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, csv, text-classification

I am new to Python and to Stackoverflow(please be gentle) and am trying to learn how to do a sentiment analysis. I am using a combination of code I found in a tutorial and here: [Python - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22034834/python-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute) However, I keep getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Python27/training", line 111, in <module>
    processedTestTweet = processTweet(row)
  File "C:/Python27/training", line 19, in processTweet
    tweet = tweet.lower()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`
```

This is my code:

```
import csv
#import regex
import re
import pprint
import nltk.classify


#start replaceTwoOrMore
def replaceTwoOrMore(s):
    #look for 2 or more repetitions of character
    pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\1{1,}", re.DOTALL)
    return pattern.sub(r"\1\1", s)

# process the tweets
def processTweet(tweet):
    #Convert to lower case
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    #Convert www.* or https?://* to URL
    tweet = re.sub('((www\.[\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','URL',tweet)
    #Convert @username to AT_USER
    tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+','AT_USER',tweet)
    #Remove additional white spaces
    tweet = re.sub('[\s]+', ' ', tweet)
    #Replace #word with word
    tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet)
    #trim
    tweet = tweet.strip('\'"')
    return tweet

#start getStopWordList
def getStopWordList(stopWordListFileName):
    #read the stopwords file and build a list
    stopWords = []
    stopWords.append('AT_USER')
    stopWords.append('URL')

    fp = open(stopWordListFileName, 'r')
    line = fp.readline()
    while line:
        word = line.strip()
        stopWords.append(word)
        line = fp.readline()
    fp.close()
    return stopWords

def getFeatureVector(tweet, stopWords):
    featureVector = []
    words = tweet.split()
    for w in words:
        #replace two or more with two occurrences
        w = replaceTwoOrMore(w)
        #strip punctuation
        w = w.strip('\'"?,.')
        #check if it consists of only words
        val = re.search(r"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", w)
        #ignore if it is a stopWord
        if(w in stopWords or val is None):
            continue
        else:
            featureVector.append(w.lower())
     return featureVector

def extract_features(tweet):
    tweet_words = set(tweet)
    features = {}
    for word in featureList:
        features['contains(%s)' % word] = (word in tweet_words)
    return features


#Read the tweets one by one and process it
inpTweets = csv.reader(open('C:/GsTraining.csv', 'rb'),
                       delimiter=',',
                       quotechar='|')
stopWords = getStopWordList('C:/stop.txt')
count = 0;
featureList = []
tweets = []

for row in inpTweets:
    sentiment = row[0]
    tweet = row[1]
    processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet, stopWords)
    featureList.extend(featureVector)
    tweets.append((featureVector, sentiment))

# Remove featureList duplicates
featureList = list(set(featureList))

# Generate the training set
training_set = nltk.classify.util.apply_features(extract_features, tweets)

# Train the Naive Bayes classifier
NBClassifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)

# Test the classifier
with open('C:/CleanedNewGSMain.txt', 'r') as csvinput:
    with open('GSnewmain.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
    reader = csv.reader(csvinput)

    all=[]
    row = next(reader)

    for row in reader:
        processedTestTweet = processTweet(row)
        sentiment = NBClassifier.classify(
            extract_features(getFeatureVector(processedTestTweet, stopWords)))
        row.append(sentiment)
        processTweet(row[1])

    writer.writerows(all)
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

The result from the csv reader is a list, `lower` only works on strings. Presumably it is a list of string, so there are two options. Either you can call `lower` on each element, or turn the list into a string and then call `lower` on it.

```
# the first approach
[item.lower() for item in tweet]

# the second approach
' '.join(tweet).lower()
```

But more reasonably (hard to tell without more information) you only actually want one item out of your list. Something along the lines of:

```
for row in reader:
    processedTestTweet = processTweet(row[0]) # Again, can't know if this is actually correct without seeing the file
```

Also, guessing that you aren't using the csv reader quite like you think you are, because right now you are training a naive bayes classifier on a single example every time and then having it predict the one example it was trained on. Maybe explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. What I'm trying is: I have a small, labelled .csv training set with 1000 positive and 1000 negative statements. Training it seems to work as I tested it by just hard coding in a test statement e.g. ' that's great!'. However, I have a file with about 10000 tweets and Facebook postings and I want to open that in this program and test the sentiment of it using Naive Bayes. I don't think I'm using csv reader correctly either but I can't put my finger on it yet..

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to cast it in method 2? tweet = str(tweet).lower

Comment: @LKT that won't do the same thing. str(tweet).lower leaves you with brackets and commas and whatnot as opposed to just lowercasing the items of the list.