# Beginner Python for sentiment analysis : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, nlp, sentiment-analysis, self

I am trying to create a sentiment analysis program using a sentiment lexicon. The sentences that will be analyzed are read from a CSV file, and after analyzed, it will be written again in a different CSV file. However, I got the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' error. The error seems to appear from this part of the code.

```
# only replace if everything succeeds
os.rename(tempname, filename)
```

Here is the full code :

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import codecs 
import re
import os
import sys, argparse
import subprocess
import pprint
import csv
from itertools import islice
import pickle
import nltk
from nltk import tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd

try:
    import treetaggerwrapper
    from treetaggerwrapper import TreeTagger, make_tags
    print("import TreeTagger OK")
except:
    print("Import TreeTagger pas Ok")

from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict


class Sentiment:
    __slots__ = ('positive', 'neutral', 'negative')

    def __init__(self, positive=0, neutral=0, negative=0):
        self.positive = positive
        self.neutral = neutral
        self.negative = negative

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Sentiment {self.positive} {self.neutral} {self.negative}>'

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Sentiment(
            self.positive + other.positive,
            self.neutral + other.neutral,
            self.negative + other.negative,
        )

#export le lexique de sentiments
with codecs.open('lexique.txt', 'r', 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as text_file:
    text_file =(text_file.read())
    #print(text_file)
dico_lexique =  ({i.split(";")[1]:i.split(";")[2:] for i in text_file.split("\n") if i}) # Spliting the text content and creating a dictionary
#print(dico_lexique)
#print(type(dico_lexique))
#print(dico_lexique)
for k, (pos, neu, neg) in dico_lexique.items():
        dico_lexique[k] =  Sentiment(int(pos), int(neu), int(neg))
'''
with open("dict_pickle", "rb") as fd:
    dico_lexique = {}
    for word, (pos, neu, neg) in pickle.load(fd).items():
        dico_lexique[word] = Sentiment(int(pos), int(neu), int(neg))
'''

stopWords = set(stopwords.words('french'))  
tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG='fr')     
def process_text(text):
    """process the specified text
    returns (words, filtered words, total sentiment score)
    """
    words = []
    filtered = []
    score = Sentiment()

    for tag in make_tags(tagger.tag_text(text)):
        word = tag.lemma
        words.append(word)

        if word not in stopWords and word.isalpha():
            filtered.append(word)

        sentiment = dico_lexique.get(k)
        if sentiment is not None:
            score += sentiment

    return words, filtered, score


filename = sys.argv[1]
tempname = filename + '~'

with open(filename) as fdin, open(tempname, 'w') as fdout:
    inp = csv.reader(fdin, delimiter=';')
    out = csv.writer(fdout, delimiter=';')

    # get the header, and blindly append out column names
    header = next(inp)
    out.writerow(header + [
        'd_lemma', 'd_filtered_words', 'Positive Score', 'Neutral Score', 'Negative Score',
    ])

    for row in inp:
        # assume that second item contains the text we want to process
        words, filtered, score = process_text(row[1])
        extra_values = [
            words, filtered,
            score.positive, score.neutral, score.negative,
        ]
        # add the values and write out
        assert len(row) == len(header), "code needed to pad the columns out"
        out.writerow(row + extra_values)

# only replace if everything succeeds
os.rename(tempname, filename)
```

Stacktrace looks like this

```
import TreeTagger OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lexicon_based.py", line 112, in <module>
    os.rename(tempname, filename)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Impossible de créer un fichier déjà existant: 'test.csv~' -> 'test.csv'
```

the lexicon looks like this  :

```
0;***;21;127;0
1;vraiment;407;156;37
2;oiseau-à-berceau;102;259;0
3;Stoph;95;308;37
4;Conscience;372;144;35
5;rançonnement;0;635;433
6;provenir;304;227;47
7;féliciteur;285;54;1
8;traversée;360;167;38
9;avant toute chose;241;108;34
```

the csv looks like this but it is much longer :

```
id;text
1; Cette thèse d'une « Wehrmacht aux mains propres » est remise en cause par les milieux scientifiques dès la fin des années 1970. 
2; Or, les avancées de l'historiographie au cours des années 1980, ainsi que le large succès de l'exposition consacrée aux crimes de la Wehrmacht, itinérante en Allemagne et en Autriche dans la seconde moitié des années 1990 et visitée par environ 900 000 personnes, achèvent de la discréditer auprès de l'opinion publique.
3; Ainsi, la responsabilité de la Wehrmacht dans le cadre de la guerre d'extermination menée sur le front de l'Est, pour la mise en œuvre du Kommissarbefehl, son soutien aux massacres de Juifs commis par les Einsatzgruppen et sa radicalisation sur le front de l'Ouest sont aujourd'hui établis et largement reconnus.
```

Comment: Please post stacktrace as well

Comment: what is stacktrace ?

Comment: logs of errors in console/terminal

Comment: Stacktrace is needed for answer but on the other hand the problem is that you want to use `lower()` attribute for a `list` type. Only the `str` type has `lower()` attribute. You can convert all elements of a list with `map` funciton.

Comment: @UpasanaMittal I update it!

Comment: @milanbalazs hello, I updated the stacktrace but I am not really understanding what you are pointing out. Could explain a little bit more with examples.

Comment: Based on the stacktrace in `__add__` method in your `Sentiment` class type of `other` variable is a list not and object or instance. It means it does not have  'positive' attribute. You should check the line 80. `score += sentiment`, here the `sentiment` variable is not correct.

Comment: @milanbalazs I think it may be related to the dico_lexique since I am having now an error when i try to convert its values in integer, any idea how can I solve this, I really lost at what solution should I try.

Comment: You want to use a not correct unpacking from `dico_lexique.items()` based on your current stacktrace. Python cannot unpack the element in `word, (pos, neu, neg)` format because `too many values to unpack (expected 3)`. Perhaps you should print the value of `dico_lexique.items()` before unpacking so you will be able to see the value and you will be able to find the root-cause of bad unpacking.

Comment: It print : {'***': ['21', '127', '0\r'], 'vraiment': ['407', '156', '37\r'], 'oiseau-à-berceau': ['102', '259', '0\r'], 'Stoph': ['95', '308', '37\r'], 'Conscience': ['372', '144', '35\r'], 'rançonnement': ['0', '635', '433\r'], 'provenir': ['304', '227', '47\r'], 'féliciteur': ['285', '54', '1\r'], 'traversée': ['360', '167', '38\r']}

Comment: I think because it is a list of values  maybe that's why it point an error

Comment: @milanbalazs I am coming at the end of my code  and I just have one more problem is the rename of the file : os.rename(tempname, filename)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Impossible de créer un fichier déjà existant: 'test.csv~' -> 'test.csv'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python text processing: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839701/python-text-processing-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-lower)

Comment: You want to rename the file with the same name as original file (In this case `test.csv`). You need to set a new name to save it. Value of `tempname` and `filename` variables musn't be same when you use `os.rename()`. Please vote if my answer or our discussion helped you.

Comment: @Adnan S it is not a duplicate